# application of maximal function inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

Given the function

$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2 \Vert x \Vert}\int_{\vert \Vert x\Vert -t \vert}^{\Vert x\Vert +t}{s h(s)ds}
$$

where $h \in C^2(\mathbb R)$, $h \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

We define the maximal function  $$(Mf)(t) = \sup_{r>0}{\frac{1}{2r}\int_{-r}^r}{\vert f(t-r) \vert}dr$$

Given the property $\Vert M(f)\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le \Vert f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ for every $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ show that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2} \le C \Vert h \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2
$$

This almost looks like a direct application of the inequality for maximal functions but the integrand of $u$ is not quite right. How can I apply it here ?

Would appreciate any help/hints

Comment: is the lower limit of the integral supposed to be $| \|x\| - t |$? (as opposed to the current $\| | x\| -t |$)

Comment: I couldn't reach out to the author of the problem so this might actually be a typo but I am not sure @CalvinKhor

Answer (score 1):

Several things should be clarified. It seems that there are many typos on your questions. If I change the definition of $u$, then I can show that the desired assertion(modified one) holds. Since it is too long to explain in the comment, I write it here. I'm not sure that why $s$ came in the definition of $u$. So I omit it.

Let $h\in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$. For $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we define
$$ u(x,t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\Vert x \Vert} \int_{t-\Vert{x}\Vert}^{t+\Vert{x}\Vert} h(s) ds&\text{if } x\neq 0,\\
0 & \text{if } x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
Our definition is well-defined since $h$ is locally integrable. Then by definition of maximal function, we have
$$ |u(x,t)| \leq M(h)(t)\quad \text{a.e. on } x.$$
Hence it follows from $L^2$-boundedness of Hardy-Littlewood maximal function that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Vert u(\cdot,t)\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2 dt\leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |M(h)(t)|^2 dt \leq C \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(t)|^2 dt=C\Vert h \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}^2. $$

If you correct typos on your original question, let me know.